# Горизонтальный список с данными!

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview, cardview

Есть `RecyclerView` с `CardView`, данные в которые подгружаются из БД. Как сделать в `CardView` горизонтальный прокручивающийся список с обычными текстовыми элементами(которые тоже из БД)?

Делать ещё один `RecyclerView` внутри `CardView` внутри `RecyclerView` считаю слишком замудренно.

Comment: В горизонтальном `RecyclerView` внутри вертикального (или наоборот) нет ничего плохого. Именно так реализовано в Google Play. Вот если вложенные скролл элементы в одном направлении, вот тут уже что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Где-то читал, что гугл не рекомендует использовать этот вариант. Видимо именно так, как вы сказали, с одинаковыми скроллами. Просто выглядит это немного громоздко (для каждого ресайкла свой адаптер).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень зависит от вашей ситуации, если у вас там несколько текстовых элементов, в которых немного текста, то игра не стоит свеч, но если у вас вдруг внутри каждой CardView должно быть много текстовых элементов, то RecyclerView самое то, это избавит вас от проблем с одновременным использованием огромного кол-ва View, как в случае с ScrollView, так как есть переиспользование. 
Еще есть вариант, что у вас должен отображаться только один текстовый элемент в один момент времени, тогда вас стоит использовать ViewPager внутри CardView

Comment: Да, элементов может быть неограниченное колличество. Значит всё-таки RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать `HorizontalScrollView`. Структура одного элемента `CardView` должна быть примерно такой:

```
<CardView
...
   <HorizontalScrollView
   ...
      <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      ....
         <TextView ... />
         <TextView ... />
       </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
</CardView>
```